# jQuery animate font-size decrease: animate shrinking from all sides

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a simple jsFiddle here where pos2 takes the css from pos1 and animates a transition to overlay pos2 over pos1. http://jsfiddle.net/4beEM/4/

As you can see, when clicked, pos2 shrinks to the upper left. Instead I would like the text to shrink on all sides, into the center. How is this possible with the code below?

```
var $pos1 = $('#pos1'),
$pos2 = $('#pos2'),
pos1Css = {
    position : {'top': $pos1.offset().top + "px",
                'left': $pos1.offset().left + "px"},
    fontSize: {'font-size': $pos1.css('font-size')}
}

$pos2.click(function() {
    $(this).animate(pos1Css.fontSize, 1000)
        .delay(100)
        .animate(pos1Css.position, 1000)
})
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4beEM/5/ something like this? I know it's not exact but let me know if my start is good or not. I also have this effect => http://jsfiddle.net/4beEM/7/

Comment: Diff 7 looks great, can you explain how the jQuery animate method is interacting with the CSS transition here?

Comment: you can animate the margin to get something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/4beEM/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/4beEM/10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up changing the `.animate` to `.css` with the use of css transitions.

(Could be done ether way but I'm not a pro with `.animate`)

The way CSS3 Transitions work is they allow the change to ease in, out, or both.

This line is for webkit based browsers and I'll break it down for you:

```
-webkit-transition: 1s ease;
```

You will need to use webkit, moz, ms, and o for the various browser out there.

The `1s` is the time frame that you want the transition to take so for this example it will ease the element for 1 second until the transition is complete.

The `ease` is straight forward in the way of targeting what type of transition you need. You can also use `ease-in-out` and a lot of different ones.

[CSS3 Transition](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp)

**What I changed in your fiddle**

```
/* I added this to pos2 to allow easing from the change with jQuery */
-webkit-transition: 1s ease;
-moz-transition: 1s ease;
-ms-transition: 1s ease;
-o-transition: 1s ease;
```

**jQuery**

```
$pos2.click(function() {
  $(this).css(pos1Css.fontSize, 1000)
      .delay(100)
      .css(pos1Css.position, 1000);
});
```

I changed it from `.animate` to `.css` because I wanted to target the css directly with the use of CSS3 easing to achieve a smoother and more desired result. Animate seems to do the scroll up to corner animation as a default.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4beEM/7/)

Comment: Best of luck in your design mate!